# Interpolation question and negative results

Tags: interpolation

I have spreadsheet . I did interpolation on it.
Negative values showed up
I used this YouTube video:
https://youtu.be/Wc4WeYN7MT0

Data is not time indexed.
Question: How do I interpret  negative values,
if results should be positive?

Comment: You have to give us more detail about the problem before we can answer.  Also, what kind of interpolation?  There is more than one.

Comment: It is  linear interpolation.Sorry about that.

Comment: You still have to show the data before we can answer any questions.  If you are interpolating between two positive function values and you got a negative value, then you made a mistake.  If you are interpolating outside the range of your data points, then perhaps you didn't make a mistake.

Comment: All data is positive. I would post a pic,but am having problems uploading

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  For the last time, it is impossible to answer the question without knowing the data.  However, if you are sure the answer should be positive, and it isn't then you made a mistake.  And no, I can't tell you what the mistake is without seeing the calculation, in case you are wondering.

Comment: I made a mistake. I redid the formula and data positive